# firebase, передача данных в GA4

Tags: firebase, google-analytics

Столкнулась со следующей проблемой.
Данные из приложения передаются в отдельный поток в GA4.

В отчет необходимо вывести число событий конверсии
(в этом случае не покупка, а "создан заказ")
и ценность события
(в этом случае "цена", а не "revenue").

Данные приходят в GA4, чтобы параметр события "цена" передать в отчет, я передаю его в специальные определения, но цифры получаются сильно больше, чем в веб потоке (сравниваем по среднему чеку, по app в 3 раза больше)

В чем может быть косяк на стороне веб-аналитики?
Может есть проверенный алгоритм работы, как собирать отчет на основе данных из firebase в таком случае?
Или это однозначно проблема на стороне разработки?